# Jquery AutoComplete to show all options without matching

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I can make autocomplete to work properly matching what is on my input text. The thing is, I want to have something like this: I search for "water" and I have a post request that gets a JSON with a list of files that contains the word "water" in their content (not in the file name). So I want it to display the drop down with the list of filenames that have that word on them even if they don't match the name of the files.

```
$.post('/autocomplete', {'search' : search}, function(data) {
                if(data.length) {
                    var availableTags = [];
                    console.log(data.length);
                    for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
                        console.log(data[i]);
                        availableTags.push(data[i]);
                        $('#system-search').autocomplete({
                            source: availableTags,
                        });

                    }

                }
            });
```

Let's say that I search for "water" and I have a document that contains that word and the filename is something like "water-example.doc". That works great, but if the same document is named "test.doc", I get the correct response from the server but the autocomplete won't show it because what's currently in the input box is "water" not "test".

Any ideas how I can make it work?

Thanks anyway